# How to check the value of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json

I have my json. I have two object on it. [image]

uid 0090000165 is on my json but when i check it, it return false.

here is my code

```js
var conf_url = "http://192.168.236.33//confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007";

 var uid = [];

    getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(obj){
           uid.push(obj['uid']);

           console.log(uid)
        })
         
         if(uid == '0090000165'){
            document.write("true");
         }else{
             document.write("false");
         }
    });


 function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: conf_uri,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      contentType: "application/javascript",
      success: function(data) {
        handleData(data);
        //console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }
```

How can i check the value to be true ? Why it is returning false?

Comment: *"Why it is returning false?"* You are testing whether an **array** with multiple elements is equal to a **string**. Why do you expect it to return true? Would you expect `['foo', 'bar'] == 'foo'` to return true? What do you really want to test?

Comment: This question is answerable by debugging the code with [debugging tools](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) available in your browser. Watch out for _errors_. [Rubber Duck Debug](http://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. If you are not sure what your code does, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger). Make sure your code is _valid_ with tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com). Only _then_, ask a question on StackOverflow and _show your research_.

Comment: Uhm sorry @Felix Kling. . I am beginner in programming. . how can check each value. . so that it will return true

Comment: Do you want to test whether the ID is **in** the array?

Comment: yes @Felix Kling. . thats what i want to do. How will i do it?

Comment: @arem: I've added to my answer to address your response to Felix above.

Comment: @FelixKling: Well, given the code above, he could also check in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array contains two entries, but on this line:

```
if(uid == '0090000165'){
```

...you're comparing it to a string for just one of them. That will call `toString` on the array, which will call `Array#join`, which will give you the string `"0090000163,0090000165"`. So you'll compare that with `"0090000165"`. That's going to be false.

In your console screenshot, the second entry has the `uid` you want, so you could do this:

```
if (uid[1] == "0090000165") {
//     ^^^----- second entry, first would be at index 0
```

...but I suspect that since `uid` contains multiple entries, you need to rework the logic, not just the comparison.

Re your answer to Felix's question:

> Do you want to test whether the ID is in the array?

where you answered "yes". I'm going to assume you're building the `uid` array for some *other* reason. You can do that by checking within your `forEach`:

```
getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
    var hasTheValue = false;

    data.forEach(function(obj){
       uid.push(obj['uid']);
       if (uid == '0090000165') {
         hasTheValue = true;
       }
       console.log(uid)
    })

     if(hasTheValue){
        document.write("true");
     }else{
         document.write("false");
     }
});
```

Or if you need to do it later, using only the array, you can use `indexOf`:

```
if (uid.indexOf('0090000165') != -1) {
  // yes it has it
}
```

If you don't need the `array` for anything, then don't build it and just do:

```
getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
     var hasTheValue = data.some(function(obj){
        return obj['uid']  == '0090000165';
     });

     if(hasTheValue){
        document.write("true");
     }else{
         document.write("false");
     }
});
```

...but again, I assume you were building the array for something else as well (since it's declared outside the function).

---

**Note**: I would recommend not using `uid` as the name of a property and of a variable where you expect a single value and *also* as the name of an array of them. But that could be my English language bias, I know not all languages differentiate between singular and plural nouns. If it's natural in your native language (I don't know if that's English or something else), ignore me.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, the screenshot relative to the `console.log` shown was misleading. Fixed.

Comment: Hello @T.J.Crowder . Why the output is false?

Comment: @arem: I explained why above.

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly you are pushing all uid of object into a array, so you have to check whether value of any of the item in your array is equal to your string value,

```
getParticipant(conf_url, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(obj){
       uid.push(obj['uid']);

       console.log(uid)
    })

     if(uid[indexOfYourChoice] == '0090000165'){
        document.write("true");
     }else{
         document.write("false");
     }
});
```